# Reload data and pass it through filter

Tags: angularjs

I've been searching for a while now, but found nothing that matches my specific question.

My scenario:
I have a list of events I use ng-repeat to display in a table. Each event has a status.
To display new events only, I use a filter.
When viewing new events, the user can press a button to change the status to 'Done'. I'd like that specific event to disappear from the table with the 'new' filter.

I've added a getEvents on success to reload the data from the server, but it won't update on my view

Here's my code:

Angular:

```
app.controller('EventsController', ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
    var info = this;
    info.events = [];

    this.getEvents = function(){
        $http.get(serverUrl+"/api/GuiEventInfos").success(function(data){
            info.events = data;
    }
}



app.controller('StatusController',['$http', function($http) {
      this.updateStatusDone = function(eventid, newStatus){
        var requestData = {"event-id":eventid, "new-status-id":2};
        $http.put(serverUrl+"/event", requestData).success(function(){
          info.getEvents();
        });
      } ...
```

Html to apply the filter:

```
...
<li ng-click="toggle = !toggle; statusFilter = { '': 'new', 'new':''}[statusFilter]">
...
```

Html to show the table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in EventsCtrl.events | filter:searchText | filter:statusFilter | orderBy:orderParam">
    <td class="center">
        <a ng-click="status.updateStatusDone(event.eventid)" class="btn-in-table" href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>  
        </a>
```

I've also tried binding the data to a model, hoping when the model changes, it will update in the view...
Added `<tr ng-model="EventsCtrl.events"...`
I'm sure there's something pretty simple that I'm missing!

Thanks for you help

**EDIT: Added angular code for EventsController**

Comment: You need to show more in your controller... what is doing getEvents?

Comment: In the getEvents function you have this: $http.get(serverUrl+"/api/GuiEventInfos").success(function(data){
        info.events = data;

Comment: Ok and how do you declare EventsCtrl.events and EventsCtrl.info ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously not very clear.
app.controller('EventsController', ['$http', '$log', function($http, $log) {
        var info = this;
I use info as 'this' because I want a reference to this controller form other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but if you want to update the view from a controller to another, consider rather using $scope.$emit('event', args); :

```
app.controller('EventsController', ['$http', '$log', function($http,$log) {
  this.events = [];
  var info = this;
  $scope.$on('needUpdate', function(event, args) {
    $http.get(serverUrl+"/api/GuiEventInfos").success(function(data){
      info.events = data;
    }
  }
}]);


app.controller('StatusController',['$http', function($http) {
    this.updateStatusDone = function(eventid, newStatus){
      var requestData = {"event-id":eventid, "new-status-id":2};
      $http.put(serverUrl+"/event", requestData).success(function(){
            $scope.$emit('needUpdate', args);
      });
}]);
```

If it doesn't work I will see further.

Comment: Not sure I understood you right... What I'm trying to do is for the data displayed in the view (in a table) will change. I know for sure the status updates, and when I refresh the page, the specific event is gone when filtered through the statusFilter. I just want the item to disappear from the table after pressing the button, because it's no longer a "New Event". If I understood correctly, I need to realod the data into the page.

Comment: yes.  $http launch $scope.$apply() which refreshes the view. If no you need to set $scope.$apply() yourself, but a good start would be to use the above trigger to launch the refresh (plus a eventually $scope.$apply(), you should success)

Comment: Ok, now I understand you. And after looking again, when I call the update status (from StatusController) I get "info is not defined, as it belongs to another controller. You're saying I need to communicate between them?